# Can the latest Anaconda package for Python 3.6 work for Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, anaconda

I have the 3.5 version of python. I want to install Anaconda, but it says on the Anaconda website the latest version of it is for Python 3.6. My question is could I still use the packages for Python 3.5, or should I install Python 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Anaconda Python, it installs into its own area and wouldn't conflict with an existing Python installation. If you already have additional Python packages installed, you will need to reinstall them for the new Python installation, preferably using a Python virtual environment. You can't use a Python virtual environment from an existing Python installation and would need to create a new one against Anaconda Python if already using one.

If your own personal code works with Python 3.5, it likely will work with Python 3.6 no problems.

So with the above caveats on re-installing additional Python packages, there shouldn't be any reason why you couldn't use Anaconda Python 3.6.

Comment: Maybe better to use [conda environments](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) than "virtual environments" (I always think of `virtualenv` when I read virtual environments ... but that could just be me) :) Otherwise good answer +1

Comment: It depends on what you need. Not all packages are in the conda packaging system.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where I couldn't run anaconda with python 3.6. What I did was to install anaconda with python 3.5. Go to https://repo.continuum.io/archive/ then download Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.